# TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, cstZone) always in CST even though in daylight savings time?

Tags: c#, timezone, utc

When I convert UTC to CST time by using code

```
DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, cstZone);
```

today Feb.27, 2016, the cstTime is in CST (Central Standard Time). But the cstTime will be CST (Central Standard Time) or CDT (Central Daylight Time) when the day is in Daylight Savings Time, for example, May 1, 2016? I check Microsoft's website

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc(v=vs.110).aspx

But it doesn't mention about this

Comment: how are you getting 10 days out when today is the `17th` not the `27th`

Comment: As an *identifier*, "Central Standard Time" actually means *Central Time (US & Canada)*.  Ignore the word "Standard" in the ID - it has no contextual meaning.  Also, read [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), specifically the section on "The Microsoft Time Zone Database".